# Does body armor render the wearer "invulnerable" to bullets?

Tags: weapons

The vicious murderer who shot up the movie theater in Aurora, Colorado last week was wearing, according to some reports, "full body armor."<sup>*</sup> Proponents of concealed-carry permits maintain that if the theater had not been a "gun-free" zone, the shooter could have been taken out in short order by an armed populace.

Given that the man was wearing body armor, is this a reasonable conjecture? If someone — an off-duty policeman carrying a standard-issue .40 caliber Glock 22, say — had been in the audience and been able to get off three shots at the shooter's center mass, would the impact, while not penetrating the chest cavity, at least have disabled the man long enough for him to be rushed and overpowered, or would he merely have shrugged it off and gone about his gruesome business?

My impression of body armor (absent any experience except from movies and TV) is that it prevents lethal injuries but perhaps transmits enough shock to the body to be extremely unpleasant, possibly disabling. My Google searches haven't led me to anything definitive (and, indeed, I feel a bit skeevy about searching for the term "body armor" on the web in the aftermath of the shooting). Can anyone shed some light on this?

**ADDENDUM**

I ask this after reading William Saletan's [contention](http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/human_nature/2012/07/the_aurora_shooting_bulletproof_vests_swat_gear_and_body_armor_refute_the_nra_.html) that crazies can escalate the mass-murder war simply by use of readily available "SWAT gear."

<sup>*</sup>The first reports of the shootings had the man in full body armor. Some people now say this was not true. Please treat this question as a hypothetical about a shooter who *was* wearing full body armor, including Kevlar vest, etc., as suggested in the Saletan article.

**OTHER EVIDENCE**

@Rusty cites a DOJ report which discusses body armor in depth. The portions of the document he quotes refer to protection against *fatalities* from penetration, which is not really what I'm asking about. A portion of the document not cited states:

> Officers and police administrators must be aware of the possibility of blunt trauma injury sustained behind body armor that has stopped a ballistic threat (i.e., not been penetrated). Any officer who has had their body armor impacted by a ballistic threat should receive a medical evaluation as soon as possible. Even though the officer shows no after effects other than soreness or a bruise, the possibility of serious internal injury still exists. A prompt medical evaluation will allow for an assessment of occult serious injury.

The crux of my question hinges on whether the "occult serious injury" may include immediate incapacitation from the blunt trauma. Although the text refers to "no after effects other than soreness or a bruise," it should be obvious that trauma resulting in soreness and bruises (such as a punch from someone who knows how to punch) can easily knock a person down, knock the wind out of him, or immediately incapacitate him from pain. For example, this personal account: when I played football in high school, I was once "speared" by a player's helmet during a play. The contact hit me right in the solar plexus, knocking me down and rendering me incapable of doing anything, even drawing a breath, for what seemed like a minute but was probably ten or fifteen seconds. If blunt trauma through body armor could result in the same sort of incapacitation, could not a deranged, body-armored shooter be stopped long enough for him to be overpowered?

Comment: There are armor penetrating rounds, sometimes referred to as cop killers, but they are illegal...  There are other non lethal weapons that would have been effective as well.

Comment: Body armor is designed to prevent penetration, but your body still has to absorb all the force of the bullet, which can still break ribs or knock the wind out of you.

Comment: "SWAT gear" is rarely inconspicuous - in other words, it practically screams "battle armor". As for various tests, this may be a useful resource (not sure if "scientific" enough): http://www.theboxotruth.com/

Comment: For example Five-seveN is legal and uses ammo specifically designed to penetrate body armor. Unless of course it's military grade body armor with ceramic inserts.

Comment: @Piskvor: Penetration is not the issue. Disabling shock trauma is.

Comment: @Ryathal: what body armour does is to distribute that force. The kinetic energy itself of pistol round isn't that great, it's only deadly because it's concentrated on small area. Also, mentioned .40 S&W is usually JHP, which is actually designed to **not penetrate** body armor.

Comment: btw. the article mentioned only shows that he was wearing a "Blackhawk Urban Assault Vest", which is just a nylon vest with lot of pouches for ammo and equipment. And the author himself acknowledges that "judging from Holmes' vest receipt, he wasn't even buying the serious stuff"

Comment: @vartec: That aside, the author's point is that "the serious stuff" exists and is available. Assume that Holmes *had* been wearing something more than a Nike track bag.

Comment: As @vartec says - given that the shooter in this case has been confirmed as *not* wearing body armor, your premise is invalid. Suggest you re-frame the question to be more focused on what the claim is you are trying to validate.

Comment: @MarkBeadles: I have added material which should make it clear to everyone that I am not talking about just this specific instance, but a case where a shooter *is* wearing sufficient body armor, as described in the Saletan article.

Comment: Clearly the absolute kinetic energy of three rounds is not overwhelming, so I think the answer becomes a series of tenuous hypotheticals about the exact make of armor, the grouping of the impacts, the window of opportunity created by the impact, etc.

Comment: @LarryOBrien: That's one way to look at it. Another way would be to find first-hand accounts of the effects given different grades of armor. I'm not asking for "how many angels can dance on the head of a pin" theorizing. If you're suggesting that this is all I can find here on Skeptics.Se, well, that's a statement in itself.

Comment: Also, body armour covers bits of the body - there is still a lot of body that can be hit or penetrated by a bullet. Certainly not 'invulnerable' just 'well protected'

Comment: 'occult' means secret (in this context), implying having no noticeable effects. Obviously 'occult trauma' cannot be immediately incapacitating.

Comment: @DJClayworth: It actually means "hidden"; they're talking about organ damage or internal hemorrhaging and the like. The point is, what causes soreness and/or bruises can be immediately painful. The point they're making is that just because you can get up and walk away from such a blow doesn't mean you aren't severely injured. Cf. concussions, etc.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Hollywood_shootout

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### While nothing is "invulnerable"; Modern body armor is extremely effective.

As suggested by [Saletan](http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/human_nature/2012/07/the_aurora_shooting_bulletproof_vests_swat_gear_and_body_armor_refute_the_nra_.html), here is the U.S. Justice Department’s breakdown on body armor...

### Armor Classifications for Ballistic-Resistant Armor

NIJ Standard–0101.04 establishes six formal armor classification types, as well as a seventh special type, as follows:

- **Type I (.22 LR; .380 ACP).** This armor protects against .22 long rifle lead round nose (LR LRN) bullets, with nominal masses of 2.6 g
  (40 gr), impacting at a minimum velocity of 320 m/s (1050 ft/s) or
  less, and against .380 ACP full metal jacketed round nose (FMJ RN),
  with nominal masses of 6.2 g (95 gr), impacting at a minimum velocity
  of 312 m/s (1025 ft/s) or less.

  Type I body armor is light. This is the minimum level of protection
  every officer should have, and the armor should be routinely worn at
  all times while on duty. Type I body armor was the armor issued
  during the NIJ demonstration project in the mid-1970s. Most agencies
  today, however, because of increasing threats, opt for a higher level
  of protection.
- **Type II-A (9mm; .40 S&W).** This armor protects against 9mm full metal jacketed round nose (FMJ RN) bullets, with nominal masses of
  8.0 g (124 gr), impacting at a minimum velocity of 332 m/s (1090 ft/s) or less, and .40 S&W caliber full metal jacketed (FMJ) bullets,
  with nominal masses of 11.7 g (180 gr), impacting at a minimum
  velocity of 312 m/s (1025 ft/s) or less. It also provides protection
  against Type I threats.

  Type II-A body armor is well suited for full-time use by police
  departments, particularly those seeking protection for their officers
  from lower velocity 9mm and 40 S&W ammunition.
- **Type II (9mm; .357 Magnum).** This armor protects against 9mm full metal jacketed round nose (FMJ RN) bullets, with nominal masses of
  8.0 g (124 gr), impacting at a minimum velocity of 358 m/s (1175 ft/s) or less, and .357 Magnum jacketed soft point (JSP) bullets,
  with nominal masses of 10.2 g (158 gr), impacting at a minimum
  velocity of 427 m/s (1400 ft/s) or less. It also provides protection
  against Type I and Type IIA threats.

  Type II body armor is heavier and more bulky than either Types I or
  II-A. It is worn full time by officers seeking protection against
  higher velocity .357 Magnum and 9mm ammunition.
- **Type III-A (High Velocity 9mm; .44 Magnum).** This armor protects against 9mm full metal jacketed round nose (FJM RN) bullets, with
  nominal masses of 8.0 g (124 gr), impacting at a minimum velocity of
  427 m/s (1400 ft/s) or less, and .44 Magnum jacketed hollow point
  (JHP) bullets, with nominal masses of 15.6 g (240 gr), impacting at a
  minimum velocity of 427 m/s (1400 ft/s) or less. It also provides
  protection against most handgun threats, as well as the Type I, II-A,
  and II threats.

  Type III-A body armor provides the highest level of protection
  currently available from concealable body armor and is generally
  suitable for routine wear in many situations. However, departments
  located in hot, humid climates may need to evaluate the use of Type
  III-A armor carefully.
- **Type III (Rifles).** This armor protects against 7.62mm full metal jacketed (FMJ) bullets (U.S. military designation M80), with nominal
  masses of 9.6 g (148 gr), impacting at a minimum velocity of 838 m/s
  (2750 ft/s) or less. It also provides protection against Type I
  through III-A threats.

  Type III body armor is clearly intended only for tactical situations
  when the threat warrants such protection, such as barricade
  confrontations involving sporting rifles.
- **Type IV (Armor Piercing Rifle).** This armor protects against .30 caliber armor piercing (AP) bullets (U.S. military designation M2
  AP), with nominal masses of 10.8 g (166 gr), impacting at a minimum
  velocity of 869 m/s (2850 ft/s) or less. It also provides at least
  single-hit protection against the Type I through III threats.

  Type IV body armor provides the highest level of protection currently
  available. Because this armor is intended to resist “armor piercing”
  bullets, it often uses ceramic materials. Such materials are brittle
  in nature and may provide only single-shot protection, since the
  ceramic tends to break up when struck. As with Type III armor, Type
  IV armor is clearly intended only for tactical situations when the
  threat warrants such protection.

### Requirements

- Types I, II–A, II, and III–A armor are required to prevent
  penetration from the impact of six bullets per panel, for two
  complete samples (front and back panels) at specified velocities and
  locations for two types of ammunition. Two of the impacts in each
  six-shot sequence must be at a 30-degree angle. A total of 48 shots
  are completed on four samples. **Furthermore, the deformation of the
  backing material (a measure of blunt trauma protection) must not
  exceed 44mm (1.73 in).** Deformation readings are taken on each panel
  at shot location 1, then at either shot location 2 or 3, whichever
  one had the highest shot velocity. The armor must meet these
  requirements while wet.
- Type III armor requirements are identical to those above, except that
  only one type of ammunition is specified, and all six test rounds are
  fired perpendicular to the surface of the armor. A total of 12 shots
  are completed (6 shots per sample).
- Type IV armor is required to resist penetration from only a single
  type of ammunition (armor piercing) and is only **required to prevent
  penetration and backface deformation greater than 44mm (1.73 in) from
  a single perpendicular impact.** A total of two samples are tested.
- The maximum allowable deformation of the clay-backing material was
  determined through an extensive series of ballistic gelatin
  measurements and experiments conducted by a team of medical experts.
  **This limit ensures protection from blunt trauma that arises from an
  impact occurring over vital locations. Even this level of protection,
  however, does not give an absolute guarantee of protection against
  internal injuries.**

Additional protection from impact blunt trama:

- **Trauma plates** are devices that can be added to the vest over a localized area (most commonly the mass center of the torso) to
  increase the wearer’s protection against blunt trauma injuries. Blunt
  trauma injuries are caused by the impact forces of the bullet against
  the armor, resulting in nonpenetrating internal injuries such as
  bruises, broken ribs, or other injuries to internal organs. Trauma
  plates can be made of a hard substance such as metal wrapped in
  rubber or ballistic fabric, or they can be made of additional layers
  of ballistic fabric, similar to an armor panel. Some manufacturers
  even build trauma plates into the armor panel itself.

According to the UCR data from the period 1990 to 1999, 290 law enforcement officers were killed while wearing protective armor (see exhibit 11). Of those officers 160 (55.2 percent) were killed by gunshot wounds to the head; 101 (34.8 percent) died as a result of gunshot wounds to the upper torso; 18 (6.2 percent) died as a result of gunshot wounds below the waist; 5 (1.7 percent) were struck by automobiles; 2 (0.7 percent) were stabbed; and 4 (1.4 percent) died by other means.

[image: Exhibit 11]

Of the 101 officers killed by gunshot wounds to the upper torso, 40 (39.6 percent) were killed when the round entered the torso region between the panels of the vest or through the arm openings, and 34 (33.7 percent) were killed when the round landed above the coverage area of the vest.

[image: Exhibit 12]

Twenty of the 101 officers killed by gunshot wounds to the upper torso died as a result of rounds penetrating the body armor. Of these 20 incidents, all were the reported result of rifle rounds, which the armor was not designed to protect against. **It is important to note that no documented fatal injury has ever resulted from a round of ammunition penetrating body armor that NIJ had approved as protection against that level of threat.**

Source: [Selection and Application Guide to Personal Body Armor](http://www.ncjrs.gov/pdffiles1/nij/189633.pdf?q=law-enforcement-officers-killed-and-assaulted-1998), U.S. Department of Justice (2001).

---

### "Shock Trauma" from impact forces

There is evidence that even without any armor humans can be pretty hard to stop:

> Short of disrupting the brain or severing the upper spinal column,
>   immediate incapacitation does not occur. Therefore, the threat remains
>   to the officer. Yet, implicit in the media presentations of law
>   enforcement encounters is the belief that with the “proper handgun”
>   and the “proper ammunition,” officers will inflict immediate
>   incapacitation if they shoot offenders anywhere in the torso. Varied
>   and multiple real-life law enforcement experiences contradict this
>   false and dangerous belief.
>
> In the authors’ ongoing study of violence against law enforcement
>   officers, they have examined several cases where officers used
>   large-caliber handguns with limited effect displayed by the offenders.
>   In one case, the subject attacked the officer with a knife. The
>   officer shot the individual four times in the chest; then, his weapon
>   malfunctioned. The offender continued to walk toward the officer.
>   After the officer cleared his weapon, he fired again and struck the
>   subject in the chest. Only then did the offender drop the knife. This
>   individual was hit five times with 230-grain, .45-caliber hollow-point
>   ammunition and never fell to the ground. The offender later stated,
>   “The wounds felt like bee stings.”
>
> Source: [One-Shot Drops: Surviving the Myth](http://valorforblue.org/Home/Publications/One-Shot_Drops_FBI_Law_Enforcement_Bulletin.pdf), FBI Law Enforcement
>   Bulletin

And when wearing armor...

> So imagine your disbelief when a threat continues to progress-even
>   after you've delivered what would normally be considered
>   "incapacitating" rounds. You think to yourself, Is it the gun? The
>   ammo? Did I hit or miss? I had to have hit, but he keeps coming.
>   Imagine the thud of realization when you determine your adversary is
>   wearing body armor.
>
> Source: [Bullet Proof: What do you do when the bad guy seems invincible?](http://www.policemag.com/Channel/Patrol/Articles/Print/Story/2003/06/Bullet-Proof.aspx)

And definitely no sign of "shock trauma" in the 1997 North Hollywood shootout:

> The patrol officers were armed with standard Beretta 92F and Beretta
>   92FS 9mm pistols and Smith & Wesson Model 15 .38 caliber revolvers,
>   Officer James Zaboravan also carried a 12-gauge Ithaca Model 37
>   pump-action shotgun, but the body armor worn by Phillips and
>   Matasareanu was strong enough to resist penetration.
>
> In this case, approximately 650 rounds were fired at two very heavily
>   armored men, who had fired approximately 1,100 rounds. The responding
>   police officers directed their fire at the "center of mass," or
>   torsos, of Matasareanu and Phillips. Each man was shot and penetrated
>   by at least ten bullets, yet both continued to attack officers.
>
> Source: [North Hollywood shootout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Hollywood_shootout), Wikipedia

Multiple hits only seemed to give these two guys a direction to shoot in.

I could find no other evidence that the force of bullet impact(s) would "have disabled the man long enough for him to be rushed and overpowered".

All things considered:

- **An "armed populace" is not going to have much effect on a determined
  psychopath in modern body armor.**

*Ps. I'm not taking a stance on guns here so please don't start that debate.*

Comment: Is this a fair summary: Different armor protects against different projectiles. It's only tested against a single bullet. In practice, wearing insufficiently graded armour has lead to deaths or injuries, but sufficient armour never has (for police). The wearer is still vulnerable to other attacks, like shots to the head or being struck by a car. You believe a bullet wouldn't knock down or incapacitate a wearer of *sufficient* body armour.

Comment: @Oddthinking Yes... except that most of the types are tested against six bullets per panel, 48 total, not one (I have a chart for that if you'd like).

Comment: @Oddthinking ..or stabbed.

Comment: +1 and thanks for the effort. Nevertheless, this does not address the issue of what I called "shock trauma" and the DOJ document you cite calls "blunt trauma"; I've amended my question with a quote about blunt trauma from that document.

Comment: @Robusto Updated with some examples.

Comment: @Rusty: Thanks for all your hard work. You've earned the check.

Comment: most of this answer is irrelevant to the question at hand, the relevant parts boil down to a couple anecdotes where getting shot with or without armor didn't stop an attacker, and some warning that internal injury is possible while wearing armor.

Comment: If you know the answer, could you post something on the availability of these different types of armour? Can I walk into a (presumably very specialized) shop and walk out with Type IV armour?

Comment: @DJClayworth: You can find Level III-A even on Amazon.com. AFAIK, there is no body armor certified to be Level IV, that would be practical in use. There are novel designs, like eg. Dragon Skin, which is claimed by manufacturer to be Level IV, but has failed to be officially certified as such. US military issued body armor is somewhere between Level II and Level III-A, but there is possibility of adding trauma plates in back and front, which are Level III but as they only cover limited part of the body, whole thing is not certified Level III.

Comment: *"Type IV armor is required to resist penetration from only a single type of ammunition (armor piercing"*? Description reads *"... It also provides at least single hit protection against the threats mentioned in Types I, IIA, II, IIIA, and III."*

Comment: The only thing I'd like to see added is the deformation information on ballistic vests. Soft vests are especially prone to this and even if the round is stopped you can still be killed or injured due to the impact trauma. The factoid I'd also add is that the body will keep working as long as the brain has oxygen (i.e. fatally wounded but still moving), but the body will also continue if nerve impulses keep running (e.g. chicken with no head).